# Bypassing Sound/Audio Files (WAV) using C

Tags: c, audio

As a part of my longer project idea to create a VST for sound design, I am now starting to learn about sound files and how they are stored in the computer.

The problem I am facing has to do with changing the bytes of a sound file. I am using C to load a basic WAV sound file, using the `putchar` function, as it gives direct access to every byte in ascii code. I found a very good place to study the WAV file [here](http://www.ievs.ch/projects/var/upload/Documentation%20Microsoft%20Wave%20File%20Format.pdf) and got into it. After dealing with the content of the header file, I wanted to get my hands dirty, so using some signal processing, I wanted to make a small script that outputs the input WAV file, in half speed.

In order to do that without changing the values of the body of the WAV file (data), I have to half the sample rate, but also half the bytes per second in order for (sample rate x block alignment = bytes per second) to be true

Some demo code I wrote for dealing with the bytes for the sample rate ( between position 25 and 28 I get the bytes for the sample rate )

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int character_of_byte, position = 0;
    while ((character_of_byte = getchar() ) != EOF) {
         position++;
         if (position >= 25 && position <= 28) { 
             putchar(character_of_byte / 2);
         } else {
             putchar(character_of_byte);
         }
    }
}
```

E.g. if the sample rate is 44100khz, this is given as an input in decimal of: 68 , 172, 0, 0 **bytes are stored in little endian form** and when halved the output in decimal has to be: 22050, which holds if we half all the above, and store **in order**: 34, 86, 0, 0  But then, if I do the same thing for the *bytes per second*, e.g. 176400khz, after I half all the decimals, the number is later interpreted as 88072.

Putchar in this case (176400khz) gets: 16 , 177 , 2 , 0 (in order), for input, but:
if I run the same script it will output: 8 , 88 , 1 and 0, which produces the number 88072.

This is wrong, because the bit shifting skips a **1** in the case of 8, since 177 is a odd number, so its last 1 digit but should have got transferred onto 8 (which was instead saved as 00001000), to create 10001000. How can I fix this, if I have to change the bytes AS they are coming in as an input?
**Keeping in mind that the last byte to the number of a 32bit number, is given first, little-endian form**

Comment: Imagine dividing a number by dividing all the digits and rounding each digit, e.g. 12345678 divided by 2 is 01122334. That's what you're doing here.

Comment: Normally, this would be done by reading the 4 bytes, creating a 32-bit number, dividing the 32-bit number, then splitting the 32-bit number into bytes again and writing them.

Comment: You are right, that's what I am doing. I am trying to immitate bit shifting to the right. That's what I would do too, but sadly I don't have that capability of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this would be done by reading the 4 bytes, creating a 32-bit number, dividing the 32-bit number, then splitting the 32-bit number into bytes again and writing them.

```
// assumes no EOF
int byte_1 = (unsigned char)getchar(f);
int byte_2 = (unsigned char)getchar(f);
int byte_3 = (unsigned char)getchar(f);
int byte_4 = (unsigned char)getchar(f);
int32_t number = (byte_1 | (byte_2 << 8) | (byte_3 << 16) || (byte_4 << 24));
number /= 2;
byte_1 = number & 255;
byte_2 = (number >> 8) & 255;
byte_3 = (number >> 16) & 255;
byte_4 = (number >> 24) & 255;
putchar(byte_1);
putchar(byte_2);
putchar(byte_3);
putchar(byte_4);
```

(of course this can be written much shorter; I wrote it like this to show the idea clearly).

If you don't mind that your code will only work on little-endian systems, you can also use `fread` or `fwrite` to read the whole number at once. In fact, this is probably how the recording program wrote the file, and this is why they use this format.

```
// still no EOF checks
int32_t sample_rate;
fread(&sample_rate, sizeof(sample_rate), 1, f);
sample_rate /= 2;
fwrite(&sample_rate, sizeof(sample_rate), 1, stdout);
```